# quitar Toltip en input tipo texto

Tags: html

tengo un campo que al darle click le sale esa info, la cual no se porque pasa, los de demas campos los tenggo igual, y no sucede como con ese.

asi que la pregunta es, porque sale ese texto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Usas alguna librería? ¿Revisaste el código CSS/Javascript relacionado con tu contenido?

Comment: si ya revise todo y nada, los demas campos estan iggual que ese pero no le sale ese mensaje pero a este si

Comment: Eso debe ser a causa de alguna librería que estás usando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las alternativas son instalar un SSL en tu sitio (lo ideal) o simplemente deshabilitar el auto-completado, si solo aplica a un input

```
<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Para todo el formulario, que seguramente es tu caso

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off">
```